# how to open already Implemented asp.net mvc solution into my system?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

unable to open  Implemented solution into my system by using vs2013 and .net framework is 452, when i am trying to open solution First i get bellow dialogue box about TFS:-

Team Foundation Server version Control :  The solution you are opening bound to source control on the following TeamFoundationServer http://tfs:8080/tfs/default connection. would you like to connect this server to try to enable source control integration? (yes/ no)  , But i'm not using TFS  here, then i clicked on No button then 
Again I got one dialogue box with source control with in this dialogue box message like"The solution appears to be under source control, but its binding information cannot be found. Because it is not possible to recover this missing information automatically, the projects whose bindings are missing will be treated as not under source control." (Ok and help) i clicked on ok. then solution opened files with message load failed.  ex:- In solution explorer projectName(load failed)

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the messages about the solution/project being under source control.  That is not causing the project not to load.

You likely don't have some required Visual Studio plugin to open that project.  The Output window should have more details as to why the project couldn't load.  Typically this is because you don't have an older version of MVC installed.